# how can i show a notification when an admin asiggne an order to a deliverer laravel 7?

Tags: laravel, notifications, laravel-7

**when i store new order i want th deliverer with "deliverer_id" get notified**

```
    public function store(Request $request)
{
    $order = Order::create([

    'deliverer_id' => $request->input('deliverer_id'),

    'product_id' => $request->input('product_id'),

    'responsible_id'=>$request->input('responsible_id'),

    'quantity'=> $request->input('quantity'),

    'client_name' => $request->input('client_name'),


    ]);

    return redirect()->route('orders.index');
}
```

**i want to show a notification say there is a "new order" on deliverer view**

```
<li class="nav-item btn-rotate dropdown">
                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle">
                        <i class="nc-icon nc-bell-55"></i>
                        <p>
                            <span>New order</span>
                        </p>
                    </a>
                    <div class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-right newor">
                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">New order</a>
                    </div>
                </li>
```

Comment: You want the notification to be showed in current page, or a facebook like notification?

Comment: i want the notification be showed on deliverer view yeah like notification

Answer (score 0):

You can try using Laravel default notification support https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/notifications. It will allow you to attach an notification to the user that will see the deliverer view. So in the view you can get the notifications by `$user->unreadNotifications` and if it isn,t empty you show the notification.

Comment: should i make a table for notification ?

Comment: If you follow Laravel official tutorial it will generate the table alone